# Equivalent of System.Xml.XmlAttribute in PCL land?

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, xmlserializer, xml-attribute

I'm attempting to convert some existing C# code into a Portable Class Library project, profile 111. Here is the code I'm stuck on:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] OtherAttributes
{
    get
    {
        return this._otherAttributes;
    }
    set
    {
        this._otherAttributes = value;
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent of that in PCL land? I see that the `XmlSerializer` compiles fine. The `XmlAnyAttributeAttribute` exists, but the `XmlAttribute` type does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be an official equivalent.

According to the MSDN page, neither `XmlAttribute` nor `XmlAnyAttributeAttribute` have an entry for PCL so that would seem to imply they are not PCL-compatible, unlike `XmlSerializer` which is listed under `Portable Class Library`.

[XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Portable Class Library
>   Supported in: Portable Class Library
>   Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1
>   Supported in: Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1
>   Supported in: Windows Phone Silverlight 8